# How to write the query to accept the input from the search box and search from MySql db (Wordpress)

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to access data from local wamp server from a Wordpress site using a Search box. I created the search box using the function `get_search_form()`, and I am unable to write a query in php to access using the same.

I have used Wamp server (localhost) and a Wordpress site.

I have tried writing an html code for the search box and tried to access the data using it. But it didn't work. I felt it's easy to run a single php script rather than a separate html and php scripts.

Code to fetch data from db:

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mydb");
$output = ''; 
if(isset($_POST["query"]))
{
    $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["query"]);
    $query = "
        SELECT * FROM clients;
        WHERE Name LIKE '%".$search."%'
        OR Aadhar LIKE '%".$search."%' 
        OR Mobile LIKE '%".$search."%' 
        OR Company LIKE '%".$search."%' 
        OR Description LIKE '%".$search."%'
    ";
}
else
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM clients ORDER BY Name";
}
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    $output .= '
      <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table bordered">
        <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Aadhar</th>
         <th>Mobile</th>
         <th>Company</th>
         <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
    ';

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)
    {
        $output .= '
           <tr>
            <td>'.$row["Name"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["Aadhar"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["Mobile"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["Company"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["Description"].'</td>
           </tr>
        ';
    }
    echo $output;
}
else
{
    echo 'Data Not Found';
}
```

I am successfully able to access all the data using this code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the function `get_search_form();` will create a Search Box and a Submit button with a wrapper form. Form method is GET so `$_POST` in your code is completely wrong. Next is the search box created using this function have the name `"s"`. The below code will be generated through the function :

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="">
    <label>
    <span class="screen-reader-text">Search for:</span>
    <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Search …" value="" name="s">
    </label>
    <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

So change your code `$_POST['query']` with `$_GET['s']`. Hope it will work for you.

Comment: You can also try the $wpdb to create your query, instead of connecting the database and other code.

Comment: I'm able to add the php code independently using php snippets but how is it possbile to add the html code for search and concurrently run its php code? I am also using Elementor editor apart from the default Wordpresss editor. I already tried adding to the code block, html block and editing the the main appearance theme codes. Please help.